# How to display each month, even if no data for this month

Tags: c#, linq, charts

The query works fine, except it only pulls the value where a month has more then zero incident, for example if January had no value, then it doesn't show January. I would like to show all months.

```
var result = tIncidentReportings
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(c => c.Date.ToString("MMM"))
    .Select(g => new { Month = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact((x.Month).ToString(), "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: Can you show us the query?

Comment: the code above is a query

Comment: @Serg I updated my answer to make more sense. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are going to have missing months for whatever months don't have any reports. You'll have to check to see which months don't have any and add them manually.

```
var result = tIncidentReportings
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(c => c.Date.ToString("MMM"))
    .Select(g => new { Month = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact((x.Month).ToString(), "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
var months = 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames.Select(s => s.Substring(0,3)).ToList();
months.foreach(m => {
    if(!results.Select(r => r.Month).Contains(m)){
        results.Add(new {Month = m, Count = 0};
});
```

Something like that

Or a rewrite of:

```
var months = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames.Select(s => s.Substring(0,3)).ToList();
var reports = months.Select(m => 
    new { 
        Month = m, 
        Count = tIncidentReportings.AsEnumerable().Where(i => i.Date.ToString("MMM") == m).Count()
    }
).OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact((x.Month).ToString(), "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToList();
```

Comment: var result = months.Select(m =>
                new {
                    Month = m,
                    Count = tIncidentReportings.Where(i => i.Date.ToString("MMM") == m).Count()
                }
            ).OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact((x.Month).ToString(), "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToList(); In this case I got an error -  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Add `AsEnumerable()` on `tIncidentReportings` before the `Where()`

Comment: Yes , it work. Thank you so much for help !!! I just created list of months manually, because your code return 13 elements(12 months and empty string, that cause an error). The your first code doesn't have error, but do nothing :).